# How to recognize similar sounds - techniques

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, speech-recognition

I would like to create a system for sound recognition. The system once being trained should be capable of recognition of similar sounds. E.g. I have few sounds such as shower, flushing toilet, fire alarm. I would install the system in a flat and train it with those sounds. Then the system should be able to recognize these sounds when installed in different flats where the sound of a shower, flushing toilet and fire alarm  has a slightly different spectrum. Is that possible? What techniques could be used? I was thinking about speech recognition techniques such as hidden markov models, nerual networks?

Comment: This is a great interesting question, but it will be said that your post belongs on DSP and not SO since it is too vague.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [pattern recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition) algorithms. For example, I believe [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) can be a solution. You first extract the spectrum signature of the training samples. Then PCA will classify a new sound to a closest known sample.

Comment: PCA can be a small part of a solution, but it's really just a way of cutting down the massive search space of signatures.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in doing this by Neural networks , i will suggest that you first read literature on Neural Networks. Also , some helpful notes on Speech Recognition by Neural networks can be found [here](http://www.cslu.ogi.edu/toolkit/old/userguide/nnet_training/tutorial.html#nntrain.exe)

Basically this is the user guide for the software that can be downloaded at this link [here](http://www.cslu.ogi.edu/toolkit/register)

I have not used the software myself, but i believe they provide the source code too. 
Hope that helps.

Edit : Also added some source code from Code Project that implements backpropogation algorithm on Neural networks . Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21171/Backpropagation-Artificial-Neural-Network-in-C)

Answer (score 0):

FFT is your friend. This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206507/Duplicates-detector-via-audio-fingerprinting) will give you some tracks.

Comment: Well I already implemented an FFT, Shazam-like algorithm based on fingerprints but this algorithm only if the recorded sound matches at least a short interval of a sound stored in the database. E.g. I have a fingerprint of a fire alarm stored in the db. Then I record an interval of this sound and it gets recognized. But if I record an interval of a fire alarm of different spectrum then it won't get recognized.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Pattern Recognition/Machine learning solutions mentioned, you should probably look at [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping), too.